# Update is not happening in Golden Gate

Tags: oracle, replication, goldengate

I have configured GoldneGate and Extract, Data pump and Replicat everything is working fine. However Update is not happening. Below are my Extract, Data Pump and Replicat file.

Extract File:

```
extract ext3
userid ogguser, password ogguser
exttrail /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/ggsrc/dirdat/lt
DDL INCLUDE MAPPED
table gg01.t2;
```

Data Pump File:

```
extract dpump1
userid ogguser, password ogguser
rmthost targetGG, mgrport 7810
rmttrail /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/ggtrg/dirdat/rt
passthru
table gg01.t2;
```

Replicat File:

```
replicat rep3
assumetargetdefs
userid ogguser, password ogguser
map gg01.t2, target gg01.t2;
```

Let me know, what parameters need to be configured to get update working.

Error which i get:

```
2016-11-28 21:45:32  WARNING OGG-01004  Aborted grouped transaction on 'GG01.T2', Database error 1403 (OCI Error ORA-01403: no da
ta found, SQL <UPDATE "GG01"."T2" x SET x."NAME" = :a4,x."ADDRESS" = :a5,x."AGE" = :a6,x."GENDER" = :a7 WHERE x."NAME" is NULL AN
D x."ADDRESS" is NULL AND x."AGE" is NULL AND x."GENDER" = :b3 AND ROWNUM = 1>).

2016-11-28 21:45:32  WARNING OGG-01003  Repositioning to rba 7748 in seqno 5.

2016-11-28 21:45:32  WARNING OGG-01154  SQL error 1403 mapping GG01.T2 to GG01.T2 OCI Error ORA-01403: no data found, SQL <UPDATE
 "GG01"."T2" x SET x."NAME" = :a4,x."ADDRESS" = :a5,x."AGE" = :a6,x."GENDER" = :a7 WHERE x."NAME" is NULL AND x."ADDRESS" is NULL
 AND x."AGE" is NULL AND x."GENDER" = :b3 AND ROWNUM = 1>.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. Below command had to be executed before executing update.

**add trandata gg01.***

Thanks!